# Make sympy write out an expression in polynomial form

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, polynomials

Currently, I have an expression of the form

```
(a+x^2) / b + x /c + xd + k
```

How can I make `sympy` to write it out in a polynomial form for `x` as

```
x^2 (.)+ x() + (.)
```

And then I want to be able to access the coefficients of that polynomial, i.e. the terms in the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Poly` class and the `all_coeffs` method. The reference is accessible here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html

This is what it would give with your example, assuming all symbols have been declared:

```
>>> pol = sp.Poly(((a+x**2) / b + x /c + x*d + k), x); pol
Poly(1/b*x**2 + (c*d + 1)/c*x + (a + b*k)/b, x, domain='ZZ(a,b,c,d,k)')
>>> pol.all_coeffs()
[1/b, (c*d + 1)/c, (a + b*k)/b]
```

After that you can access each coefficient with its position.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand the expression and collect on `x` you can then request the desired coefficients:

```
>>> eq = d*x + k + x/c + (a + x**2)/b
>>> ex = collect(eq.expand(), x); ex
a/b + k + x*(d + 1/c) + x**2/b
>>> ex.coeff(x**2)
1/b
>>> ex.coeff(x)
d + 1/c
>>> ex.subs(x, 0)  # the constant
a/b + k
```